# Why it takes so long to create Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, containers, azure-container-instances

I'm using the docker compose command to spin up 2 containers in Azure Container Instances, by using ACI docker context.
Sometimes, it takes only a while (below 1 min) to get the containers up and running. However, often it takes much longer (up to 5 minutes I would say). Does somebody have an idea why the speed of ACI creation and making the containers run can be slow? Can it be improved for example by running the containers in a resource group belonging to a different Azure "location"?

Thank you very much for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody here will be able to tell you exactly why there is a difference, could be anything, starting from the time it takes to find a slot in an underlying compute cluster to the time it takes to pull the image from your container registry. As far as I know there is no SLA on the startup time.

So yes, you could try different Azure regions, to maybe get lucky in finding a region which is less busy on the ACI side. But this might or might not always help. (The resource group has nothing to do with it, as it is just a logical container)